# Content overlapping on another div when I use pre tag

Tags: html, css, dom, bootstrap-4

My webpage looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to enter some code block with horizontal length like this:

```html
<pre><code>
URL = "https://example.com/73876544657687988976987654465768798657687988976/"
</code></pre>
```

Once I enter this snippet, the content of the main overlaps on the right section. I want my content to stay inside main (if there's an overflow in pre, there could be a scroll)

I have tried to fix the CSS of `div` that contains the content in main (position, overlap-x, etc.).

I don't think that there's an issue with the CSS of `pre` (I am using prism.css), as it's working fine at other places.

Comment: Do you want a horizontal scroll bar to appear, or for the text to break to next row?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Though, I don't want to modify the CSS of pre tag, as it works perfectly fine (breaks to next row), at other places. So, I suspect there's some issue with my main layout.

Comment: Please take a look at my latest answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the example bellow.
By default `overflow` property is `visible`. We need to make it `auto` so a scroll bar will appear in case of overflowing (your case). If there is no overflowing, no scrollbar will appear. That means `auto`.

To understand it better, check documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

```css
.section{
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}
.main{
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='section'>
  section
</div>
<div class='main'>
  <pre>
    <code>
URL = "https://example.com/73876544657687988976987654465768798657687988976/"
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
<div class='section'>
  section
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the scroll for the lengthy text(URL) apply these to `pre` tag

```
pre{
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;

}
```